# Using Meteor as a classic backend

Tags: node.js, api, rest, meteor, backend

I'm wondering if Meteor can be used as a classic backend for a Rest API and websockets.

**I found Restivus[1] which is spectacular, I can turn Meteor into a full Rest API with security and everything. But how to use sockets now ? It is the only part that I can't found.**

I found this approach interesting so I can build a backend for already existing front ends (angular/ember) and also for DDP clients.

This way I don't have to build two different backends based on different frameworks (express for classic Rest API and Meteor for DDP).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the socket.io nodejs package as follows:

1) Start by installing meteorhacks:npm from Atmosphere which will give you npm support in your Meteor project.

2) edit packages.json to include socket.io and/or socket.io-client.

3) in your code use something like this to import the package:

```
io = Meteor.require('socket.io-client')
```

You can import websockets (or other npm packages) similarly.